# Como fazer uma Lista Encadeada em Assembly?

Tags: assembly, lista, lista-encadeada

Tenho um trabalho de faculdade e preciso fazer uma lista encadeada em *assembly*, gostaria de saber como fazer o *loop* para inserir todos os elementos na lista e mantê-los ligados.
A lista deve conter os dados de uma locadora (nome do filme, ator principal, numero de copias do filme...)

Este é o código que fiz ate agora, ele recebe os dados do usuário e armazena em um espaço reservado (aqueles .space são pra reservar memória pra cada campo), o que eu preciso é que após inserir o primeiro registro eu consiga guardar a posição dos próximos (encadear os registros).

```asm
.section .data

programtitle:       .asciz      "\n Gabriels Library\n\n" # 

asktitle:   .asciz  "\nWrite the title of the book"
askcategory:    .asciz  "\nWrite the category of the book"
askcharacter:   .asciz  "\nWrite the main character"
askyear:    .asciz  "\nWrite the year it was published"
askcopies:  .asciz  "\nWrite the number of copies the library has"

mostratitulo:   .asciz  "\nTitle: %s" # show the title
mostracategoria: .asciz "\nCategory %s" # show category
mostraator: .asciz  "\nCharacter %s" # show character
mostraano:  .asciz  "\nYear %d" #show year
mostracopias:   .asciz  "\nNum of copies: %d" #show number of copies

formstr:    .asciz  "%s"
formint:    .asciz  "%d"
formch: .asciz  "%c"
enter:  .asciz  "\n"

NULL:   .int 0

ttitulo:    .space 44
tano:   .space 4
tcopias: .space 4
tcategoria: .space 24
tator:  .space 44

prox:   .int NULL
naloc:  .int 124

le_dados:
    pushl   %edi

    pushl   $asktitle
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %edi
    call    gets

    popl    %edi
    addl    $44, %edi
    pushl   %edi

    pushl   $askyear
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %esp
    pushl   $formint
    call    scanf
    addl    $4, %esp

    popl    %edi
    addl    $4, %edi
    pushl   %edi

    pushl   formch
    call    scanf
    addl    $4, %esp

    pushl   $askcopies
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %esp
    pushl   $formint
    call    scanf
    addl    $4, %esp

    popl    %edi
    addl    $4, %edi
    pushl   %edi

    pushl   $formch
    call    scanf
    addl    $4, %esp

    pushl   $askcategory
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %esp

    call    gets

    popl    %edi
    addl    $24, %edi
    pushl   %edi

    pushl   $askcharacter
    call    printf
    addl    $4, %esp
    call    gets
    popl    %edi
    addl    $44, %edi
    movl    $NULL, (%edi)

    subl    $124, %edi

    RET
```

Comment: Oi, gabriel, bemvindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, mostre o código que você está tentando desenvolver. Podemos ajudar com ele, mas não fazer do zero para você.

Comment: poderia explicar o pq do seu código não funciona e onde está tendo mais dificuldade? entender código assembly já não é fácil, quando é dos outros então é pior ainda.

Comment: esse código só recebe os dados do usuário e armazena em um espaço reservado (aqueles .space sao pra reservar memoria pra cada campo) o que eu preciso é que após inserir o primeiro registro eu consiga guardar a posiçao dos próximos (encadear os registros)

Comment: Veja se esses links te ajudam:
http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-34/ass34_7.html e http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45999/linux-nasm-assembly-linked-list-implementation

Comment: Não sou um praticante de programação em assembly, apesar de ter sido minha primeira linguagem.
Posso lhe indicar este link [Using Two Common 'Compression' Techniques](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/utils/article.php/c8747/Using-Two-Common-Compression-Techniques.htm), que certamente deve usar alguma forma que estrutura de dados com encadeamento, pois implementa compactação de dados Huffman em assembly.<br>
Veja o código no fonte Huffman.cpp, pois pode lhe dar uma boa orientação de implementação.

Answer (score 4):

Recomendo você fazer em C, e na hora de compilar (com o GCC) você compila desta forma

```
gcc.exe programa.c -o codigo.asm -S
```

Ai o compilador irá converter seu código C em Assembly, ai você poderá ver como ele foi feito!